# Cannot start service from the command line or debugger. How can I tell which service?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to debug an ASP VB web site project I recently took over.

I start debug while in the home page.

I recieve the following error:

> Cannot start service from the command line or debugger. A windows
>   Service must first be installed(using installutil.exe) and then
>   started with the ServerExplorer, Windows Services Administrative tool
>   or the NET START command.

How do I tell what service the program is trying to start?

I viewed other questions with this error to no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to debug not an ASP/ASP.NET application, but a Windows Service project - it cannot start from the debugger. If your solution has multiple projects, make sure to set Startup project to the one you're working with.

If you do need to debug the service, compile and install it as the message suggest and then attach Visual Studio debugger to the process running the service.

Comment: Is there any way to tell what service it is trying to start?

Comment: Take a look at all projects in your solution. Project highlighted in bold will be the project you're trying to start. Also, in solution properties - it will be set as a startup project

Comment: P.S. If you do not have multiple projects - that means the only project you have *is not* an ASP.NET project but indeed a service

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to start a window service from vs.net.You have to start the application as a service and the attach the debugger. You can make extra project, commandline with:

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    // Startup as application
}
```

to start the serice as a commandline application.

Or you can add a brakpoint in de service to attach the debugger with:

```
Debugger.Break()
```

[Configure and starting a service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758812%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)